# I cannot run any project because of gyp error. How can I fix this: npm ERR! gyp verb cli

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, vue.js, npm

Whenever I run my code I always get the same error. I uninstall node and npm and reinstall. But now there is no "node_modules" and I get the same error. How can I fix it?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python /Users/bng/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/bng/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:399:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/bng/Desktop/deneme/12-vue-spa/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bng/.npm/_logs/2022-03-24T08_05_44_961Z-debug-0.log
```

There isn't node-sass and node-gyp. When I tried to install them I also got the same error. I cannot install anything.

Comment: What does `which -a python2` show when you execute it in your terminal?

Comment: nothing comes out
```
(base) MacBook-Pro:12-vue-spa bng$ which -a python2

(base) MacBook-Pro:12-vue-spa bng$
```

Comment: Ok so it looks like python2 is not installed or cannot be found, but whatever you want to install expects python2 to be installed. So you have to install it using e.g. brew.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yarn install throws error: gyp verb \`which\` failed Error: not found: python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744726/yarn-install-throws-error-gyp-verb-which-failed-error-not-found-python2)

Answer (score 25):

I solved this problem by changing the node version to 14.15.1

Comment: In above comments,
It is mentionded node 14 works, [you can downgrade 14 from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version#answer-61491579)

Comment: I tried node 18.x but i get the error. downgrading to 14.15.5 solved the issue for me.   Ahsant Hamvatan.

Comment: NOTE: DOWNGRADING is not a good option! It's like suggesting to go with old version of software that is end of life. Please UPVOTE the answer with yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass. Don't compromise security of your program.

Answer (score 12):

Do not use node-sass anymore. Remove 'node-sass' in package.json. pls use 'dart-sass'.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass (dart-sass is default now)

---

update answer at 2023/08/24

the answer still stand. we can see  node-sass  ->  dart-sass -> sass.

now pls use sass
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass

Comment: Indeed! Removing `node-sass` from package.json made `npm install` finish successfully, finally!

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73312114/6118794

Comment: 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass' says: "This package has been deprecated. Author message: This package has been renamed to 'sass'."

Answer (score 5):

Please don't waste your time running the suggested command by others.
Please uninstall node.js and use the Node v14.x.
It will solve it automatically.

Answer (score 5):

With most of the operating systems removing python2 this is a common issue for most projects. It definitely affected 4/5 of my recent projects after upgrading to current Linux/Debian Stable which removed python2.

The solution is for system to start using python3 and in order to do that you need to..

Solution/Solved is:

node-sass is actually at fault. Python2 is required until version 6.0.0. Normally you would upgrade to latest 7.0.3 but node-sass is currently obsolete, so we will swap to sass project.

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass
```

I've given more details on reasoning why here, or alternative dart-sass if you use "render() and renderSync() functions".:

[Solved-ERR!gyp-info-using-node-gyp-3.8.0-gyp-verb-which-failed-Error-not-found-python2](http://wwwhww.news/u/cwSNkeLNXf#Solved-ERR!gyp-info-using-node-gyp-3.8.0-gyp-verb-which-failed-Error-not-found-python2)

Affected:

- node.js /react web apps
- Elixir/Phoenix assets
- Android apps
- Vue.js projects

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and did this:

```
 1. npm install node-sass
 2. npm install  
 3. npm ci
 4. ng serve --open (to launch the project ).
```

Answer (score 1):

## !important

i run into the same issue. ANd What I recomend to you is to install **nvm** to control your node version instead of unistalling the current version causing other problems with the existent projects.

### NVM Installation Guide

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-use-nvm-on-windows/

or

> https://tecadmin.net/install-nvm-macos-with-homebrew/

### After installation

After you are sure that you'd installed **nvm** successfully you can do:

1. `nvm --version` to check if nvm is successfully installed
2. `nvm install [desired node version]` ex.: `nvm install 14.0.0`
3. `nvm list` to check all node versions installed
4. `nvm use [desired version]` to change between node version ex.: `nvm use 14.0.0`

### Conclusion

As I mention above, instead of unistalling your node versions you can install different versions of node and changing between then avoid future errors.

### Be Happy even with  bugs

Comment: I don't understand the negative vote here it makes perfect sense to manage multiple versions rather than uninstalling. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me.

Try:

```bash
npm cache clean --force

npm uninstall node-sass
```

Uninstall node modules from your project

```bash
npm i sass --save
```

Comment: I think it is generally a "devDependencies" so it should be installed with ```npm i sass --save-dev```

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall the nodejs and reinstall the node version 14.21.3

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.21.3/

Answer (score -1):

**try**

- npm uninstall node-sass --force
- npm install --save-dev sass --force
- npm i --force

Comment: Please update your answer and add your code to a codeblock. Thanks