# node-sass install ERROR with Node 18 version

Tags: node-sass

```
npm install node-sass

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path D:\RND\redux-toolkit\node_modules\node-sass

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js

npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\RND\redux-toolkit\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=

npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

npm ERR! gyp verb cli [

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\RND\\redux-toolkit\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='

npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]

npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1

npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.1.0 | win32 | x64

npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []

npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []

npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory

npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is 

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing 

"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - 

"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is 

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing 

"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "py.exe" to get Python 3 executable path

npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is 
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python

npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (D:\RND\redux-toolkit\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:330:47)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (D:\RND\redux-toolkit\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:159:21)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\RND\redux-toolkit\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:228:18)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (D:\RND\redux-toolkit\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:294:16)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:395:5)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:407:5)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044

npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\RND\\redux-toolkit\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="

npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\RND\redux-toolkit\node_modules\node-sass

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.1.0

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1

npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-02T09_17_47_530Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 24):

## Don't use node-sass

`node-sass` is deprecated and won't be supported. Instead use the new version which is `sass`.

You can uninstall the old and install the new one with this command

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

Works with no further changes needed

Answer (score 2):

Node 18 won't be supported till https://github.com/sass/node-sass/pull/3257 lands and a v8.0 release is pushed to NPM

Answer (score 0):

For my case my node version was 18. I upgraded node version to 20 then
npm uninstall node-sass after that yarn solved