# How to I modify my system settings to not get a node-gyp error whenever I run the npm ci command?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

So I'm using the npm ci command and I suddenly get this error. Any clue on fixes?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
npm ERR!   adler32.c
npm ERR!   compress.c
npm ERR!   crc32.c
npm ERR!   deflate.c
npm ERR!   gzclose.c
npm ERR!   gzlib.c
npm ERR!   gzread.c
npm ERR!   gzwrite.c
npm ERR!   infback.c
npm ERR!   inffast.c
npm ERR!   inflate.c
npm ERR!   inftrees.c
npm ERR!   trees.c
npm ERR!   uncompr.c
npm ERR!   zutil.c
npm ERR!   win_delay_load_hook.cc
npm ERR!   zlib.vcxproj -> C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack\build\Release\\zlib.lib
npm ERR!   erlpack.cc
npm ERR! c:\users\maddi\downloads\zeppelin-master\zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2544): warning C4996: 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor': Do signature check in accessor [C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\maddi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\v8-template.h(838): note: see declaration of 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor'
npm ERR! c:\users\maddi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\zlib.h(1422): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
npm ERR! c:\users\maddi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\zlib.h(1422): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'gzfread' [C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
npm ERR! c:\users\maddi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\zlib.h(1422): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'z_size_t' [C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
npm ERR! c:\users\maddi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\zlib.h(1454): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
npm ERR! c:\users\maddi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\zlib.h(1454): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'gzfwrite' [C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
npm ERR! c:\users\maddi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\zlib.h(1454): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'z_size_t' [C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
npm ERR! c:\users\maddi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\zlib.h(1709): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'z_size_t' [C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
npm ERR! c:\users\maddi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\zlib.h(1745): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'z_size_t' [C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.2 found at "C:\Users\maddi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.9.33403.129) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\maddi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\maddi\\Downloads\\Zeppelin-master\\Zeppelin-master\\backend\\node_modules\\erlpack\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\maddi\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.15.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\maddi\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.15.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\maddi\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.15.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\maddi\\Downloads\\Zeppelin-master\\Zeppelin-master\\backend\\node_modules\\erlpack',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\maddi\\Downloads\\Zeppelin-master\\Zeppelin-master\\backend\\node_modules\\erlpack\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\maddi\Downloads\Zeppelin-master\Zeppelin-master\backend\node_modules\erlpack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\maddi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-12T10_59_03_022Z-debug-0.log
```

It should have installed all packages but I get that error.
I'm not too sure how to fix this. I am currently on windows 11 and I'm using the latest python version and the LTS node version. I've been at it for a few days but nothing really seems to be working out. Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Do you have node-sass in your deps ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I think so. I just ran an npm install node-sass and I got a very similar error

Comment: I sometime get this when I swap node versions with `n` (or `nvm` might cause this too). I have to run `npm build` to fix it

Comment: @apokryfos I just tried to use `npm build` but it just tells me that isn't a commnd.

Comment: That seems to have been removed since v7 of npm, it should now be `npm rebuild`

Comment: @apokryfos Just tried `npm rebuild` and it does show a node gyp error

Comment: I had to downgrade to Node 18.12.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cannot run any project because of gyp error. How can I fix this: npm ERR! gyp verb cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71599040/i-cannot-run-any-project-because-of-gyp-error-how-can-i-fix-this-npm-err-gyp)